# How can I approximate a chance constraint in a computationally tractable way?

Tags: optimization, chance-constraints

I want to solve an optimization model that contains a constraint like
$$
\Pr[F(x,\xi)\leq0]\geq1-\varepsilon
$$
where $x$ are my decision variables, $\xi$ is a random vector, and $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ is some tolerance that measures how certain I want to be to satisfy my constraint. Is there a general way to solve such a problem?

(Disclaimer: I'm asking this because the Nemirovski and Shapiro paper was hard for me to read, and I wanted a brief, accessible summary).

Answer (score 14):

In general, chance constraints are difficult to handle computationally. Given a fixed $x$, is it often very difficult to even compute the value of $\Pr[F(x,\xi)\leq0]$, making the incorporation of such a constraint into an optimization model quite troublesome.

One possible approach is outlined in the 2006 paper by Nemirovksi and Shapiro entitled [Convex Approximations of Chance Constrained Programs](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/SIOPT_Bern_2006.pdf). In this paper, the authors propose techniques for creating *conservative* approximations of chance constraints (i.e., approximations with smaller feasible regions). See [this paper by Shabbir Ahmed](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11590-013-0624-7) for convex relaxations.

In what follows, we'll assume that for all $\xi$, the function $F(\cdot,\xi)$ is convex in its first argument (if this is not the case, you'll have to do some hard thinking). We'll also assume $F$ is real-valued (not vector-valued---i.e. not a joint chance constraint). For the remainder, we'll deal with the complement of the given constraint, that is, we'll deal with $\Pr[F(x,\xi)>0]\leq\varepsilon$.
It is well known that [the probability of an event is equal to the expectation of an indicator function on that event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000005C-QINU%60%22%27%7F). That is,
$$
\Pr[F(x,\xi)>0]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{F(x,\xi)>0\}}].
$$
The **BIG IDEA** behind this approximation scheme is to replace the discontinuous, non-convex indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{\{\cdot\}}$ with some nicer function---let's call it $\psi(\cdot)$. Ideally, we want $\psi$ to be continuous, convex (for easier computing), and be greater than (or equal to) the indicator function (so that our approximation is conservative).

Now, because $\psi(t)\geq\mathbf{1}_{\{t>0\}}$, we have that
$$
\Pr[F(x,\xi)>0]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{F(x,\xi)>0\}}]\leq\mathbb{E}[\psi(F(x,\xi))].
$$
Hence, if we enforce $\mathbb{E}[\psi(F(x,\xi))]\leq\varepsilon$, this implies $\Pr[F(x,\xi)>0]\leq\varepsilon$ (just like we want).

So how do we pick $\psi$, the approximation to the indicator function? Here are three popular choices:

1. $\psi(t)=\max\{1+t,0\}$. This choice is actually equivalent to [Conditional Value-at-Risk (CVaR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_shortfall).
2. $\psi(t)=(1+t)^2$. This choice is equivalent to approximating the chance constraint using [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) (see, e.g., slide 10 of [these slides](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/chance_constr.pdf)).
3. $\psi(t)=\exp(t)$. This choice is advantageous because the function $\mathbb{E}[\exp(tX)]$ for a random variable $X$ is known as a [moment-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function), and has some nice, well-studied properties.

In fact, you can do a little bit better than this approximation. Nemirovski and Shapiro show that you can actually enforce
$$
t\mathbb{E}[\psi(\tfrac{1}{t}F(x,\xi))]\leq{t}\varepsilon\quad\leftarrow\text{If you only remember one thing...}
$$
for any $t>0$, and the approximation is still valid. This function on the left-hand side is actually convex in $t$ (as long as $\psi$ is convex)---this is called a *perspective function* (see, e.g., Section 3.2.6 of Boyd and Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/)). So we can just throw in a new variable $t\geq0$ and enforce the above constraint, and get a tighter approximation.

**Toy Example**

Suppose we have the constraint
$$
\Pr[\xi_1x_1+\xi_2x_2\leq2]\geq0.9.
$$
where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are non-negative decision variables, $\xi_1\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(1)$, and $\xi_2\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(1/2)$. The true chance constraint can be evaluated using the law of total probability (see code below). For the conservative approximation, we take $F(x,\xi)=\xi_1x_1+\xi_2x_2-2$, $\varepsilon=0.1$ and $\psi(t)=\exp(t)$. As noted above, this choice of $\psi$ is equivalent to the MGF of the random variable $\xi_1x_1+\xi_2x_2-2$, which is given by
$$
\exp\big[\lambda_1(e^{x_1/t}-1)+\lambda_2(e^{x_2/t}-1)-2/t\big]
$$
where $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=1/2$. Hence, for any $t>0$, the following is a conservative approximation:
$$
t\cdot\exp\big[(e^{x_1/t}-1)+\tfrac{1}{2}(e^{x_2/t}-1)-2/t\big]\leq{t\varepsilon}
$$
An example of the true feasible region (light gray), and the approximation for $t=0.4$ (dark gray) are shown here:

[image: example of a conservative approximation]

Python code to produce this plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

def main():
    l1, l2 = 1.0, 0.5
    tau = 2.  # Chance constraint rhs
    eps = 0.1  # Chance risk tolerance
    tee = 0.4  # Conservatism a parameter
    num_points = 500
    X = np.linspace(0, 1, num_points)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, X)

    approx = tee * np.exp(
        l1 * (np.exp(X / tee) - 1) + l2 * (np.exp(Y / tee) - 1) - (tau / tee)
    )
    exact = np.vectorize(evaluate_poisson_cc)(X, Y, l1, l2, tau)

    # Plot the results
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.contourf(X, Y, exact,  levels=[1. - eps, 1.],  colors="k", alpha=0.2)
    ax.contourf(X, Y, approx, levels=[0., tee * eps], colors="k", alpha=0.4)
    ax.set_xlabel("$x_1$"); ax.set_ylabel("$x_2$")
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    plt.show()


def evaluate_poisson_cc(x1, x2, l1, l2, tau, tol=1e-10):
    """ Evaluate P[x1 * Z1 + x2 * Z2 <= tau] where Zi ~ Poisson(li)
    """
    assert tau > tol
    if np.abs(x1) < tol and np.abs(x2) < tol:
        return 1.
    if np.abs(x1) < tol:
        return stats.poisson.cdf(tau / x2, l2)
    if np.abs(x2) < tol:
        return stats.poisson.cdf(tau / x1, l1)
        
    max_value = np.floor(tau / x2)
    n_values = np.arange(max_value + 1)
    v1 = stats.poisson.pmf(n_values, l2)
    v2 = stats.poisson.cdf((tau - n_values * x2) / x1, l1)
    return np.dot(v1, v2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer. Is it possible to post or upload somewhere, the codes that you have written for the toy example? @david-m

Comment: @SAH Sorry for the long delay--I just added the code (there was actually a bug in the old version, so it is corrected now)

Answer (score 12):

In addition to David M's excellent answer, another approach which sometimes can be useful is to use integer programming. Specifically, if your distribution of $\xi$ is discrete (e.g. taking a sample-average-approximation of uncertainty is a reasonable approach) and you are willing to make a big-M assumption on $F(x, \xi)$ then another way to model a chance constraint is using integer programming.

In particular, if we have $L$ realizations of $\xi_i$ total, and they all occur with equal probability, then we can let $z_i=1$ if $F(x, \xi_i) \leq 0$ and $0$ otherwise, and model the chance constraint exactly using the following big-M constraints:
$$
F(x, \xi_i) \leq M(1-z_i), \forall i \in \{1, .., L\},\\ \frac{1}{L}\sum_i z_i \geq 1-\epsilon.
$$
This approach cannot be applied to a general continuous distribution, because it relies on the support of $\xi$ being discrete. However, there are some fairly general conditions under which the optimal solutions $x^*_L$ from sample-average-approximations of size $L$ converge almost-surely to the optimal solution $x^*$ for the full continuous distribution of $\xi$ as $L \mapsto \infty$, and therefore discretizing a continuous distribution $\xi$ and applying a big-M approach to the discretized distribution is often a reasonable idea.

I believe that some other approaches have since been shown to be faster (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.07377.pdf) for instance), but the integer programming approach seems worth knowing.

Further reading: chapter 5.7 of [this book](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/people/faculty/Alex_Shapiro/SPbook.pdf), and [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-008-0247-4).